# Is there a way to make multiple input radio checked?

Tags: php, html, css, database

I have a problem with code and I can't figure out the solution. So I have a registration form, form contains different user registration(Private and Company) and those are input type radio, so when you select private it shows some parts of form and if you select company it shows some parts. My problem is with "gender", in Private there is Male/Female/Other options with input type radio, but when you select Company there is (don't know how to translate this in English) Firma/Öffentlich/Verein. They use the same name(bestellung[anrede]) but not the same values and it differ on selected user registration.

So I've tried selecting the first child that is showing with jQuery, but it only selects in 'Private', when I switch to 'Company' nothing is selected.

```html
<fieldset class="">
   <legend style="font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: 6px; border: none;">*</legend>
      <input id="" class="" type="radio" name="" value="">
      <label style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin-right: 5px;" for=""><span></span></label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="">
   <legend style="font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: 6px; border: none;">*</legend>
      <input id="" class="" type="radio" name="" value="">
      <label style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; margin-right: 5px;" for=""><span></span></label>
</fieldset>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('fieldset .hide_if_firma').each(function () {
      $('input:radio[class=rwd-radio]:nth(0)').prop('checked', true);
   });
   $('fieldset .show_if_firma').each(function () {
      $('input:radio[class=rwd-radio]:nth(3)').prop('checked', true);
   });
});
```

If anyone has any idea how to change that, I would be most definitely grateful.

Comment: For multiple radio checked, its `checkbox`. Now you may change style to make it looks like radio button. Logically its CHECKBOX.

Comment: Where is your jQuery code? I think you select the first Radiobox and not the first **visible** radiobox ....

Comment: But it can't be checkbox since it shows only first fieldset when 'Private' is selected. It shows only three options for each and only one can be selected.

Comment: @Marcus And how should I select first visible input radio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select only the first visible one and break after this.

```
// loop over all visible inputs with the given name
$('input[name="bestellung[anrede]"]:visible').each(function(){
  // take element and set it to checked
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
  // this is a "break" for this loop (btw a "return true" == continue)
  return false
})
```

EDIT: include Barmar's comment and remove the \

EDIT: Add JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1xkt2mdL/ (https://jsfiddle.net/1xkt2mdL/#&togetherjs=PFw0LUG1JH)

Comment: You don't need any backslashes if you put it in quotes: `$('input[name="bestellung[anrede]"]')`

Comment: But it won't work. Checking one of the radio buttons will automatically uncheck the others.

Comment: You don't need to use `.each()`, you can do `$('input[name="bestellung[anrede]"]').prop("checked", true)`

Comment: but then you check all. And radio boxes allow only one to be checked. So the Browser or jQuery or God will select one. And you never know witch one :) Better use the **visible** selector to get only the visible. You can add the **:first-child** selector to avoid the loop.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried both solutions Marcus and @Barmar, but seems like neither one works.. Maybe trying to put input:radio to point it out more.

Comment: Maybe it's some other backend code that's blocking it from working on my side.